# How do I roleplay a character with low wisdom?

Tags: dnd-5e, ability-scores

Each of the ability scores have their own quirks when it comes to negative numbers. 1 in strength is they can't wear clothes because they're so weak, 1 in con is their blood can't clot and they constantly break bones, 1 in intelligence makes you a vegetable. What would a 1 in wisdom be?

Comment: Where are you getting the low score definitions? Are they inventions of your own? If so, this seems like an idea generation topic and is too broad and primarily opinion based. To ask the question in a more answerable way for this site, you may want to state your goals for the character and leave it more open-ended (so that experts can provide [good subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) answers based on experience). For more information on how to ask a good question, visit our [Help Center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Skills related to Wisdom include Perception and Insight, so you could play someone poor at those. Perhaps your character has poor vision, poor hearing, or is extremely gullible and easily deceived. Maybe this leads to poor animal handling abilities, as you don't notice when they are getting aggressive or afraid.

Answer (score 2):

**For the headline question: However you like - its your character**

With respect to your first sentence ("Each of the ability scores ..."): this is just wrong. There is nothing special about having 1 in *any* ability score apart from the mechanical effects of having a -5 on skills/attacks related to that ability.